# I think my version of compiler is posessed? (1 && 0 detected in if statement)

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, mingw32

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool contains(std::vector<int> list, int value){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list[i] == value) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool containsdouble(std::vector<double> list, double value){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list[i] == value) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> step = {0};
    std::vector<double> value = {};
    value.push_back(double(4)/double(3));
    int i = 4;
    int j = 3;
    while(1){
        if(contains(step, (0)) && !containsdouble(value, double(i)/double(j))){
            std::cout << contains(step, (0)) << " && " << !containsdouble(value, double(i)/double(j)) << " caught on\ni = " << i << ", j = " << j;
            return 0;
        }
        i*=2; j*=2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: This is the result]

This is only when -O2 or -O3 and only occurs in some versions of compiler but not all versions of compiler. This result was done with the MinGW compiler, but again it only occurs in some versions of compiler.

So what is does is check if 0 is in step, which it is, and if not of 4.0/3.0 is in value, which it isn't. 1 && 0. Then it goes into the if statement anyway and gives the result.

Comment: Using `==` in combination with floating-point values is nearly all cases wrong.

Comment: @t.niese In this case the representation should be the same. OP is doing exact same operation twice (`(double)4/3`)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: Do you have `fast-math` flag?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: `4./3` is a compile time value, `(double)i/j` is runtime value.

Comment: I do not have -ffast-math but again this will only work in some versions of compiler but not all versions so this will not be reproducible for everyone.

Comment: Can you compile and run both 32bit abd 64bit executables? Possibly this could be related to the 10 byte floating point used by the x87 FPU.

Comment: The version of compiler I'm using does not support 64-bit but only 32-bit. However it only works in some versions of compiler so I can't switch to a different version of compiler because then it would not be reproducible (I know this because I have tested in different versions of compiler)

Comment: Again, which compiler are you using?

Comment: `This is only when -O2 or -O3 and only occurs in some versions of compiler but not all versions of compiler. This result was done with the MinGW compiler, but again it only occurs in some versions of compiler.`

Comment: Yes, but **which** versions

Comment: It's impossible to detect it!

Comment: you must know at least one version where it doesn't produce the result you expect?

Comment: But it's impossible to detect what it is!

Comment: However the script goes into the if block to then itself print out the logical inconsistence. It went into the if block, but the printed version says 1 && 0, which should be impossible.